# php mysql update multiple table with same field?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 5 table in a single database and same time of field name. the things i need to is bellow

```
UPDATE `customers` SET  `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old';
UPDATE `radacct` SET `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old';
UPDATE `radcheck` SET `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old';
UPDATE `radreply` SET `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old';
UPDATE `radusergroup` SET  `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old';
```

now how can i update all table in a single query? I have tried with

```
UPDATE `customers`,`radacct`,`radcheck`,`radreply`,`radusergroup` SET  `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old'
```

but its giving me error

> ## 1052 - Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous

looking for solution

Comment: Just because those column identifiers have the same name doesn't mean you can refer to all of them at once. You still need to specify each column individually in your query:

Comment: try a multi query and does that column actually exist and in all tables? what you tried won't work btw. you need a multi query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is one call to query on php side, i would do:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `customers` SET  `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old'; UPDATE `radacct` SET `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old'; UPDATE `radcheck` SET `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old'; UPDATE `radreply` SET `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old'; UPDATE `radusergroup` SET  `username`='new' WHERE `username`='old';");
```

If you want one query on mysql side, well since those table updates are not dependant from each other, i think there is no point as it makes a heavy query (as you can see on other answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with help of join.

```
  UPDATE customers, 
           radacct, 
           radcheck,
           radreply,
           radusergroup  
    SET    customers.username = "new", 
           radacct.username = "new", 
           radcheck.username = "new"
           radreply.username = "new"    
           radusergroup.username = "new"
   WHERE   customers.username = "old"
            AND radacct.username = "old"
            AND radcheck.username = "old" 
            AND radreply.username = "old"  
            AND radusergroup.username = "old"
```